# ASP.net server control checkbox misunderstanding

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use the server control for an asp checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="generalInformation"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    class="SetupChecklist"
    name="generalInformation"
    CssClass="SetupChecklist"
    runat="server" />
```

However it does not seem to be retaining the class, which I need it to do.  Am I missing something?

Here is how it renders on the web page:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$generalInformation"
    id="generalInformation">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah.......

this is the problem:

`runat="server"` checkbox is render to `span + input`...

the span gets the class not the input....

```
 <span class="SetupChecklist" class="SetupChecklist" name="generalInformation">
<input id="generalInformation" type="checkbox" name="generalInformation" /></span>
```

Comment: Hrm, is my only option that to not use the server control and just add runat=server to my html input box?

Comment: @JamesWilson it is probably what i'd do... if i really needed the class on the input itself.... , or you can add the class via server side to the input field...

Comment: since i am using a template and don't feel like redoing most of their css I think I will have to take that route.  Thank you for finding that out for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [`CssClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property instead:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="generalInformation"
    ClientIDMode="Static"
    name="generalInformation"
    CssClass="SetupChecklist"
    runat="server" />
```

**Edit**: I've only just seen that you've already tried it. Ok, `CssClass` actually applies the class to a span that wraps the check box, so try this instead:

```
generalInformation.InputAttributes("class", "SetupChecklist");
```

Comment: is there a benefit to doing it this way, rather that adding runat=server to just the html input element and opting to not use the server control?  I'm fairly new to asp.net so be gentle. :)

Comment: @JamesWilson: That depends on your requirement. If you want to handle the CheckedChanged event or use other additional properties, then use the CheckBox control. It might be sufficient for you to use the html control. In general it's good practise to use Servercontrols when you need to access and use them on serverside.

Answer (score 1):

It will render the HTML like below.

```
<span class="SetupChecklist" class="SetupChecklist" name="generalInformation">
     <input id="generalInformation" type="checkbox" name="generalInformation" />
</span>
```

---

Assuming that you are trying to design the input tag.

Now your style sheet can be like below for the `<input>` tag

```
<style type="text/css">
    .SetupChecklist input
    {
        border:0px;
    }
</style>
```

Originally, the `span tag` was occupying the `class` information.

Comment: I could do it that way, but I would have to either modify or rewrite a lot of CSS to cover all of the styles in the template.  Not something I wish to do.  =(

Comment: I was, and I appreciate the feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the class attribute and just use the CssClass

Comment: Does not fix it sadly.  Royi above found out it adds the class to a span tag and not the input element, which messes the connection i had with css and jquery.